# vb.net WebBrowser Control - Blue Outline Around Submit Buttons

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

When I view certain sites using the WebBrowser control in vb.net, the submit buttons of forms have this blue border around them and I can't seem to figure out why or how to get rid of it.

I have a Windows Form Application with a WebBrowser control on it, and this is the code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.bing.com")
    End Sub
End Class
```

The border/outline is most visible on Bing, but can be seen on other sites like Google as well.

Using IE11
[image: Using IE11]

Using WebBrowser control
[image: Using WebBrowser control]

Comment: If you go to https://www.whatismybrowser.com/ in your webbrowser control, what version of IE does it show you're using?

Comment: Google "vb.net feature_browser_emulation" for relevant hits.

Comment: @ChaseRocker It shows Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7

Comment: @HansPassant I have FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION set to 11000 currently, which I know is working because once removed it shows that compatibility mode is active on the site Chase Rocket suggested.

Comment: I just tested the webbrowser control: The whatismybrowser site shows IE11, Bing displays like your first image. I also set browser emulation to IE7. whatismybrowser shows compatibility mode IE7 active and Bing still shows like the first image. So I'm not sure what's up with your second image, but that doesn't look like a simple border around the icon, it looks like something different.

Comment: @ChaseRocker That's odd.  I had someone else here try it too and they got the same result I did.  It's only when the search box has focus, but that should have happened when the form first loaded for you.